# trying to search through sql data shown in php, not working

Tags: php, sql, search

Hi I have a SQL database which contains information about properties. Above this I have a search button which searches the propertyLocation field to display relevant ones.

Example:

```
Property ID 1, 5 Bedroom House, London
Property ID 2, 3 Bedroom House, Scotland
Property ID 3, 2 Bedroom Flat, Cardiff.
```

At the top all i'm trying to do is put a search in which if the user types "london" only property ID 1 will be shown. I cannot seem to get it to work! My code is as follows:

Displaying the properties and search box:

```
<table id="propertyTable">

    <form method="post" action="search.php">
        <input type="text" name="search" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="   Search   ">
    </form>

    <th>Property ID</th>
    <th>Property Name</th>
<?php   
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Property");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $pID = $row['pID'];
                $pLocation = $row['pLocation'];

                echo "<tr data-row='$pID'><td>$pID</td>";
                echo "<td>".$pID."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$pLocation."</td>";
            }
?>
</table>
```

Search.php code:

```
<?php

$sql="SELECT * FROM Property
WHERE pLocation like '$search%'";

$result=mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());


while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$pID=$row["pID"];
$pLocation=$row["pLocation"];
}
?>
```

Please note I am connecting to my DB at the top. The first form does display the properties however, search just does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

- I keep getting errors, Use of undefined constant search and undefined variable DB...
- Errors fixed, it leads to search.php but nothing is displayed! Current search.php code is:

  ";
              echo "".$pID."";
              echo "".$pLocation."";
          }
  ?>

Comment: Have you seen if $result has some results? Have you tried to launch the query on your sql manager?

Comment: If your entry in db is `something somethinelse London` and you search for `London` like `London%` it will not work, you'd better try `%London%`

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how to do so. I am completely new to this..

Comment: Where are you passing the data to the $search variable?

Comment: Try to understand what I'm talking about. I assume $search is the string that the user enters? So if it is `London` it will become `London%` in your query because of using `'$search%'` in the query. You'd need the wildcard to be passed at the beginning. Read about the MySQL LIKE SEARCH

Comment: And also read about `register_globals` because I suspect this kind of problem aswell

Answer (score 1):

You need to get your $search var out of the $_POST array:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
```

edit:

Saw your second error about DB. You said: "Please note I am connecting to my DB at the top. "  but if you are getting $db undefined, there is an issue with this.  Maybe follow the syntax on your other page and use the assumed connection like:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

On the first page there is output echoed. You need to mimic that on your search results:

```
            $pID = $row['pID'];
            $pLocation = $row['pLocation'];

            echo "<tr data-row='$pID'>";
            echo "<td>".$pID."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$pLocation."</td></tr>";
```

I tried to fix some of the wonky table structure; the first page seemed to output one long row?

Comment: undefined variable DB +  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null give

Comment: This solved the errors but now nothing is display: Current search code looks like this:

Comment: Your sample code doesn't have any display... I assumed it was below? Adding it to answer now.

Comment: <?php
$search=$_POST['search'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM Property
WHERE pLocation like '%search%'";

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$pID=$row["pID"];
$pLocation=$row["pLocation"];
}
?>

Comment: Your edit doesn't look like the code I put in the answer here. If you want, just copy the `echo` rows from the original page and put them in the same spot on the search.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, i.e. initialize the `$search` variable with the `POST` value

```
 <?php

 $search  = trim($_POST['search']);

 $sql="SELECT * FROM Property
 WHERE pLocation like '$search%'";

 $result=mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());


 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $pID=$row["pID"];
    $pLocation=$row["pLocation"];
  }
 ?>
```